# Scatterplot with x axis only

Tags: scatter-plot, plotly-python

I have a dataframe 'Spreads' where one of the columns is 'HY_OAS'. My goal is to draw a horizontal line (basically representing a range of values for 'HY_OAS') and plot the column mean on that line. In addition, I wanted the x axis min/max to be the min/max for that column and I'd like to include text boxes annotating the min/max. The problem is I'm not sure how to proceed because all I have is the below. Thanks for any and all help. The goal is the second image and the current code is the first image.

```
fig8 = px.scatter(x=[Spreads['HY_OAS'].mean()], y=[0])
fig8.update_xaxes(visible=True,showticklabels=False,range=[Spreads['HY_OAS'].min(),Spreads['HY_OAS'].max()])
fig8.update_yaxes(visible=True,showticklabels=False, range=[0,0])
```

[image: Current]

[image: Goal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following what you describe and what you have coded

- generate some sample data in a dataframe
- scatter values along x-axis and use constant for y-axis
- add mean marker
- format figure
- add required annotations

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# simulate some data
Spreads = pd.DataFrame({"HY_OAS": np.sin(np.random.uniform(0, np.pi * 2, 50))})
# scatter values along x-axis and and larger point for mean
fig = px.scatter(Spreads, x="HY_OAS", y=np.full(len(Spreads), 0)).add_traces(
    px.scatter(x=[Spreads.mean()], y=[0])
    .update_traces(marker={"color": "red", "size": 20})
    .data
)

# fix up figure config
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_visible=False,
    yaxis_visible=False,
    showlegend=False,
    paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
)

# finally required annootations
fig.add_annotation(x=Spreads["HY_OAS"].mean(), y=0, text=Spreads["HY_OAS"].mean().round(4))
fig.add_annotation(x=Spreads["HY_OAS"].min(), y=0, text=Spreads["HY_OAS"].min().round(2), showarrow=False, xshift=-20)
fig.add_annotation(x=Spreads["HY_OAS"].max(), y=0, text=Spreads["HY_OAS"].max().round(2), showarrow=False, xshift=20)
```

[image]

#### straight line

- build base figure as follows
- then same code to add annotations and configure layout

```
fig = px.line(x=[Spreads["HY_OAS"].min(), Spreads["HY_OAS"].max()], y=[0,0]).add_traces(
    px.scatter(x=[Spreads.mean()], y=[0])
    .update_traces(marker={"color": "red", "size": 20})
    .data
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome and is almost exactly what I need, thank you so much. The x axis is actually just supposes to be a solid line instead of multiple individual points. How would I make that change?

Comment: so all you really want to do is draw a line, plot the mean and have min and max on either end?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. Is the main idea here that the core graph is a line from xmin to xmax and there is an overlay scatterplot for the mean? Is there a way to reposition the mean label so it is below the marker? Also, what does ".data" represent?

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I understand what's going on. Thank you so much for the help, very much appreciated.